# How to sort photos inside a shared album in the Photos app in macOS, iOS, or iPadOS?

Tags: macos, ios, photos, ipados, album

How to sort photos inside a shared album in the Photos app in macOS, iOS, or iPadOS?

Answer (score 1):

After sharing multiple photos and videos in a shared album, each user with access to the shared album can independently sort the order of the media as they wish on their own device.

The procedure to sort the photos is slightly different between iOS, iPadOS, and macOS. See below

### Sorting in iOS (similarly in iPadOS with the difference of how to navigate to the shared album)

1. Open the Photos app
2. Go to albums
3. Go to the shared album in question
4. Tap on the "More" icon on the top right corner. The icon is three horizontal dots
5. Tap Sort (up and down arrows icon)
6. Choose one of the three available sorting orders

### Sorting in macOS

1. Launch the Photos app
2. Go to the shared album in question located on the left navigation bar
3. Choose view on the menu bar (bar above all applications starting usually with "File")
4. Go to Sort
5. Choose one of the three available sorting orders